# Quick unit-aware calculator

Tags: ubuntu, cross-platform, calculator

I want to be able to press a keyboard combination, start typing a mathematical expression that includes units and slightly advanced math (not just a four-function calculator), and get a result immediately, in units that I specify, that I can copy and paste.

- Currently I open Firefox and press Ctrl+K, type in the search box, and it usually gives me a result in the drop-down from [Google Calculator](http://www.google.com/help/calculator.html).  It doesn't always, though, so I press "=" at the end, wait for a result, remove the equals, wait for a result, realize it doesn't understand the way I typed a unit, open the result in a new tab, etc. it sucks.
- [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is smarter, but very much slower, and the output is all images, not text, and I don't have a quick widget for it, if such a thing could even exist.
- [GNU units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/) has a ton of units, which is great, and I [can define my own units](http://gist.github.com/127445), which is great, but they have to be written in specific, unintuitive ways, it doesn't handle much advanced math, and I'd need to open a terminal, start units, etc.  I hate the command line.
- I wasted a lot of time trying to make front-ends for `units` in Deskbar and [Launchy](http://gist.github.com/127286), but I'm not a real coder and I don't use either of those anymore.

Any other solutions or enhancements of these?

(Cross-platform is best)

The ideal unit-aware calculator would be able to handle all of these:

- `7 nV/sqrt(Hz) ⋅ sqrt(20000 Hz - 20 Hz) → μV` = 0.99 μV
- `sqrt(4*k*25 °C * 1 kΩ * (20 kHz - 20 Hz))` = 0.57357 μV
- `3.5 billion kilowatt-hours per year` = 399.5 MW
- `60 billion kWh per year` = 6.849 GW
- `1/sqrt(2 mH * 2 nF)` = 500 kHz
- `1/(2*pi*10 kΩ * 22 µF)` = 0.7234 Hz
- `1/(2·π·100 Hz·30pF) → ohm` = 53.05 MΩ
- `−10 dBV + 4 dB + 10 dB − 12 dB → dBu` = -5.782 dBu
- `94 dBSPL → Pa` = 1.00237 Pa
- `54 inches + 2 feet → cm` = 198.1 cm
- `12 V ÷ 141.5 µA` = 84.8 kΩ
- `16 bit * 44.1 kHz * 2 → kbit/s` = 1411 kbit/s
- `1 hundred V / 5 ohms` = 20 A
- `furlong per fortnight → cm/minute` = 0.9979
- `attoparsec/microfortnight → in/second` = 1.004
- `1 ft / speed of sound` = 0.89576 ms

Comment: What is the level of complexity of the problems you are trying to solve?

Comment: What did you try to script that a combination of `bc -l` and `units` couldn't do?

Comment: Can you give an example of using `bc -l` and `units` together?  I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @honk: sounds like something you should post in an answer (y'know, with an example).  @endolith: use @ for [comment notifications](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) so the user gets notified when you reply to them.

Comment: @endolith: Actually my comment was too fast, `bc` doesn't gain you anything if you do not plan to define your own functions . The trigonometric, exponential and logarithmic function are all already defined in `units` (only Bessel functions are missing).

Comment: @quack quixote: There should be a reply button for that.

Comment: @endo: suggest it on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you like... :)

Comment: this should be on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @phuclv Yes, but it didn't exist when this was asked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm very impressed with [Qalculate!](https://qalculate.github.io/)**.**

[image: Qalculate! screenshot]

Comment: +1 So am I, although my user interface (the Qalculate plasmoid for KDE) doesn't offer a way to express a result in specified units. I work around it by dividing my result by the units I want. I forget whether the full interface, if it even still exists, can do that. (Just so it's clear: even with the UI limitations, it's still my favorite calculator for anything I don't need Mathematica for)

Comment: I don't see standard temperature, speed of sound, and I don't understand how it handles dB, but I am also very impressed.  I wish the answers appeared after a short delay without pressing Enter, too.  But these are all things I can complain about.  :)

Comment: @endolith: You can go into Edit>Manage Variables>Physical Constants and Edit>Manage Units and add your own or edit existing entries. I've never seen a calculator complete a calculation after a timeout. One thing I would like to see in this program is history navigation using arrow keys or scroll-and-click with the mouse instead of having to copy-paste from the history.

Comment: Google Calculator in the Firefox search bar completes as I type, though I have to prod it sometimes by typing an equals sign.  The thing I wrote for Launchy also displays the result as you type, though it was slow because of the way it accesses Units.

Comment: @DavidZ: (meanwhile) Qualculate offers the "to" command to convert units: "2m to cm" will express the result in cm.  Note that (lib)qalculate comes with qalc, a command-line version that uses readline and can recall history with the arrow keys or Ctrl-R (and other neat CLI tricks provided by readline, like Tab completion, copy/paste, undo, etc., also found in e.g. Bash).

Comment: This is a really nice program.  Now that I've stopped using Linux, I wish it were supported in Windows.  :/

Comment: There is now a Windows version: https://github.com/Qalculate/qalculate-gtk/releases

Comment: Also, it's available for Mac through MacPorts and Homebrew. Here's the [downloads page](https://qalculate.github.io/downloads.html) which includes links for the Windows and Linux versions and links to the Mac version pages at MacPorts and Homebrew.

Answer (score 5):

**[insect](https://github.com/sharkdp/insect/)** has both web- and terminal-based versions. It does support parsing, handling and conversion of physical units, for example:

```
>>> 2min + 30s

   = 2.5min

>>> 40000km / speedOfLight -> ms

   = 133.426ms

>>> 6Mbit/s * 1.5h -> GB

   = 4.05GB

>>> 2J·s + 3W

  Unification error:

    Cannot unify unit W (base units: kg·m²·s⁻³)
            with unit J·s (base units: kg·m²·s⁻¹)
```

Comment: This thinks `dB` means "decibyte".  :/

Comment: @endolith: Thanks! Tracked here: https://github.com/sharkdp/insect/issues/67

Answer (score 2):

For a easily scriptable solution you might want to have a look a the `sympy` python module.

```
$ cat conv.py

#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from sympy.physics.units import *
from sympy.printing.pretty.pretty import pprint
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
from sympy import *

# adding extra units is easy
parsec = 3.26163626*ly

if __name__ == '__main__':
  s_input = sys.argv[1]
  s_unit  = sys.argv[2]
  input = eval(s_input)  # input string
  unit  = eval(s_unit)   # output unit

  print 'Converting:'
  pprint(input)
  print
  print str((input/unit).evalf()) +' '+ s_unit
```

which gives e.g. for some moderately ugly expression converted to mm:

```
$./conv.py 'tanh(3*m/(2*m))*sinh(60*deg)*1*parsec' 'mm'


Converting:
                           /π\
3.08574615554565e+16*m*sinh|--|*tanh(3/2)
                           \3 /

3.48955431541888e+19 mm
```

Of course this is really studpid code that does no checking thet unit
compatibility of the input and output, so you
might end up extra units in the result.

```
$./conv.py 'c' 'parsec'

Converting:
299792458*m
-----------
     s

9.71539598165644e-9/s parsec
```

Comment: Also see https://launchpad.net/python-quantities

Comment: @endolith: It all really only depends on what kind of math you want. The basics are in `units`, but obviously it doesn't have symbolic algebra or higher math.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly share your ideas about an ideal calculator and the disadvantages of using [GNU Units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/) and Wolfram and rolled my own online calculator which I put online at [PhyCalc.com](http://phycalc.com). It does its own unit algebra for SI units and uses [GNU Units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/) for conversion to other units, or as a fallback when the expression itself contains non-SI units.

Its aims to interpret Unicode input where it makes sense. And tries to be smart about guessing the exact quantity and corresponding unit. It automatically inserts SI-prefixes. (much like my trusty old Casio pocket calculator does in "ENG" mode)

Some comments about your "ideal calculator" inputs and responses:

> sqrt(4*k*25 °C * 1 kΩ * (20 kHz - 20 Hz)) = 0.57357 μV

Its not exactly accurate to automatically assume °C to be an absolute temperature. Also k is not exactly an unambiguous symbol for the Boltzmann constant. However this should give you the required answer:

```
sqrt(4*1.38064852e-23J/K*(273.15K+25 °C) * 1 kΩ * (20 kHz - 20 Hz)) in μV
```

These fail in GNU Units:

> 3.5 billion kilowatt-hours per year
>
> 1 ft / speed of sound

GNU Units alternatives could be:

```
3.5 billion kWh per year
1 ft / mach in ms
```

> [1/(2·π·100 Hz·30pF)](http://phycalc.com/?in=1%2F%282%C2%B7%CF%80%C2%B7100+Hz%C2%B730pF%29) → ohm

You can leave out the "→ ohm" part. That is what I meant with "being smart about guessing the quantity" :-).

> −10 dBV + 4 dB + 10 dB − 12 dB → dBu

GNU Units has some dB conversion, but it is defined as 10^(x/10) which is a scalar that it will not add to a voltage, where you assume that the calculator should recognize that it should be scaling Voltage instead of Power and should apply scaling of 10^(x/20) instead. That would be very cool, but is a bridge too far for gnu units I'm afraid. This will at least give you the correct answer using GNU Units:

```
 1V*dB(-10)^0.5*dB(4)^0.5*dB(10)^0.5*dB(-12)^0.5 → dBu
```

But I can see why you may find that un-intuitive.

Otherwise I think [PhyCalc.com](http://phycalc.com) may come pretty close to your ideal calculator.

To have fast access to it, I map my dedicated calculator keyboard key to it by adding to the following string (REG_SZ) name/value pair in the Windows registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18]
"ShellExecute"="http://phycalc.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

Wolfram Alpha is capable of crunching math and doesn't require you to download or install anything.

[Check here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Math.html) for how to use its math functions.